# unique output with select bulk and loop

Tags: oracle, loops, plsql

I have data structure looking like this:

[image]

So in column_a I have figures form 1 to 5, but in column_b I have elements which a repeating. And I want to loop column_b elements so that only unique are shown.

Here my pl/sql:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON SIZE 100000

DECLARE
    var_column_name_a  VARCHAR2(30);
    var_column_name_b  VARCHAR2(30);
BEGIN
    SELECT
        column_name_a,
        column_name_b
    BULK COLLECT
    INTO
        var_column_name_a,
        var_column_name_b
    FROM
        table_name;

    FOR i IN var_column_name_a.first..var_column_name_a.last LOOP
        dbms_output.put_line(var_column_name_b(i));
    END LOOP;

END;
/
```

My current output is this:

```
type_a
type_b
type_b
type_b
type_c
```

but I need this

```
type_a
type_b
type_c
```

How to achieve this?

Comment: or maybe I ask differently: How to show only the elements which belong to each other i.e if the loop at the first element of var_column_name_a(i) = 1 to show only the first element of var_column_name_b(i) = 1?

Answer (score 0):

**No way** that code you posted produces anything, it is invalid. You can't bulk insert into scalar variables, so either you faked code you wrote, or the output.

---

Anyway: to me, the simplest option seems to be a separate select of distinct values into another collection. Here's how:

Sample data:

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM test;

      COLA COLB
---------- ------
         1 type a
         2 type b
         3 type b
         4 type b
         5 type c
```

Procedure:

```
SQL> DECLARE
  2     TYPE tr IS RECORD
  3     (
  4        cola   NUMBER,
  5        colb   VARCHAR2 (10)
  6     );
  7
  8     TYPE tt IS TABLE OF tr;
  9
 10     l_tab         tt;                      --> for all rows in TEST table
 11     l_tab_unique  SYS.odcivarchar2list;    --> just for COLB
 12  BEGIN
 13     SELECT cola, colb
 14       BULK COLLECT INTO l_tab
 15       FROM test;
 16
 17     SELECT DISTINCT colb
 18       BULK COLLECT INTO l_tab_unique
 19       FROM test;
 20
 21     DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('all rows -------------');
 22
 23     FOR i IN l_tab.FIRST .. l_tab.LAST
 24     LOOP
 25        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (l_tab (i).cola || ' ' || l_tab (i).colb);
 26     END LOOP;
 27
 28     DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('unique rows ----------');
 29
 30     FOR i IN l_tab_unique.FIRST .. l_tab_unique.LAST
 31     LOOP
 32        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (l_tab_unique (i));
 33     END LOOP;
 34  END;
 35  /
```

The result is:

```
all rows -------------
1 type a
2 type b
3 type b
4 type b
5 type c
unique rows ----------
type b
type c
type a

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: Yes, I have constructed it and missed the declaration of TYPE/ record and so on. But you correctly understood the question. So, you are suggesting 2 different "select bulk collect into" statements.  But can an uniqueness be achieved by using only one "select bulk collect into" statement?

Comment: I don't think so, because the first one fetches both columns, so the "best" you could hope for is to get distinct pairs of values if COLA and COLB have duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

First off a simple *select distinct col_b bulk ...* is sufficient for what you are asking for. But assuming you may want a list of the other column you can get it with LISTAGG function. Also for this you can use an older (but still valid) form of BULK COLLECT where each column in the select is collected into a independent collection. So you wind up with the structure:

```
select col_a, col_b 
  bulk collect 
  into collection_a, collection_b
  ... ;
```

Specifically here with LISTAGG for col_a:  (see [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=e3ee66a099a9e13537f31ae12b793d10))

```
declare 
   type array_t is table of varchar2(256) ; 
   k_tab constant varchar2(1) := chr(09); 
   col_a_list array_t; 
   col_b_list array_t;

begin
    select col_b, listagg( col_a, ',') within group (order by col_a) a_list
      bulk collect 
      into col_b_list, col_a_list      --<<< BULK COLLECT into separate collection
      from t1
      group by col_b
      order by col_b;  
  
    dbms_output.put_line ('col_b') ; 
    dbms_output.put_line ('_____'); 
    for list_cnt in 1 .. col_b_list.count
    loop
        dbms_output.put_line(col_b_list(list_cnt));
     end loop;     
    
    dbms_output.put_line (' ') ; 
    dbms_output.put_line ('col_b' || k_tab || 'col_a_list') ; 
    dbms_output.put_line ('_____' || k_tab || '__________') ;
    for list_cnt in 1 .. col_b_list.count
    loop
        dbms_output.put_line(col_b_list(list_cnt) || k_tab || col_a_list(list_cnt));
     end loop;  
end ;
```